# Auto-mount encrypted volume on boot with key in crypttab

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, dm-crypt

I have a LUKS-formatted volume and crypttab that contains the following:

```
cryptdata    UUID=3e26bc03-...    /etc/cryptdata.key
```

When the system boots, systemd asks me the password for this volume twice and after me just pressing the Enter key it successfully mounts the volume using the given key. How to deal with this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with this behaviour"? It seems like everything is doing what it's supposed to. What do you *expect* to happen compared to what does happen?

Comment: @etskinner, I want it to stop asking for passwords (for there's none, I've initially formatted it with key file instead of password) and just use the file.

Comment: Keyfile contains random data, like `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/keyfile.key bs=1024 count=4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `noearly` option as the fourth field for that device in your `/etc/crypttab`; it could be that the version of `/etc` being used during early boot doesn't have the key.

Failing that, you can always mark it `noauto` and have a systemd unit or script mount it significantly later in the bootup process.